# How do I remove this underline on my code in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, underline

I have had this underline since I set up VS Code on my new PC and I can't remember where it is from. I don't think it is an extension as I have checked and I only have standard ones installed. Rather, I think it's a setting that I must have enabled. Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

[image: image showing underlines]

[image: list of extensions]

I have tried looking for an `underline` configuration on `settings.json` but didn't find anything.

Comment: @user yes it's funny that op wants to enable it when I want to disable it lol.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution, go to `settings` > search `bracket pair` and disable `bracket pair horizontal`.